# iPython Magic Commands Unicode Error and Issue with 'str'

Tags: python, unicode, ipython, ipython-magic

I am trying to use iPython magics in my IPython 4.0.3 with a Python 2.7.11. However, using a magic command, e.g.:

```
%load_ext pep8_magic
```

leads to the following error.

> ```
> TypeError: unicode argument expected, got 'str'
> ```

Does anyone have an idea of what could be going wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: Does that error have a traceback?

Comment: Do you have a mix of python2 and python3 issue?